# Encrypted class loading in jboss

Tags: jboss, classloader

We are using JBoss 5.1 to deploy our application. But now we want to encrypt few classes in our war. When we encrypt a .class file, then Jboss throws error. This is understandable because jboss's class loader doesn't know that the class is encrypted. 
I want to extend the JBoss's class loading functionality and implement code to decrypt the .class file before it loads.

I guess this must be possible. I have been reading jboss developer manual and am not able to figure out how I can do it.

Has anyone else already done anything similar. Any suggestions or help would be great.

Thanks,
Irfan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question was answered in JBoss community discussion forum:

https://community.jboss.org/thread/221073

Answer (score 0):

It's probably possible (though needs work), but there are strong opinions that it doesn't really make sense or provide benefits. Check out [this discussion](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/javaqa/2003-05/01-qa-0509-jcrypt.html?page=1).

In a nutshell, every decrypting classloader must provide well-documented, clear definition of a class to java runtime, and from there it is easily readable for anyone, either by hooking up a java agent or replacing rt.jar with ones own code.

Comment: Thanks Eis. I had seen that link and yes, I understand that the encrypted class files must be decrypted at some point and if someone is determined to get the source then he can still do so. But I just want to make that someone struggle before he gets our code.

Comment: I am currently trying to extend jboss BaseClassLoader and implement our decryption technique before loading the class. I am horribly stuck in this process. I would appreciate if you can tell me if there is any other way (possible easier than working with jboss jars)

Comment: @irbash is there some specific thing you're having problems with? might be a good thing to add to the question also

Comment: The problem i am having is that I cannot use my extended classloader with jboss 5.1 (My extended classloader takes care of decrypting the .class files before asking jvm to load it)

Comment: If I modify the BaseClassLoader (inside jboss-classloading-spi.jar, which is inside lib folder of jboss) and do the decryption in BaseClassLoader's loadclasslocally method then it works. But I dont want to modify jboss jars because I cannot ask my clients to use modified jboss jar.